# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool ayuda

Tags: php

Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

```
<section class="content-header">

        <?php

        $exp = explode("/", $_GET["url"]);

        $columnaC = "id";
        $valorC = $exp[1];

        $carrera = CarrerasC::CarreraC($columnaC, $valorC);

        echo '<h1>Estudiantes de: '.$carrera["nombre"].'</h1>';

        ?>
        

    </section>
```

[image]

And this is the error that shows in the browser

```
echo '<h1>Estudiantes de: '.$carrera["nombre"].'</h1>'; //this is line 30
```

Comment: echo $carrera["nombre"] and see if that is not an array and please write in eglish

Comment: The return of `CarrerasC::CarreraC($columnaC, $valorC)` is FALSE. Debug that function to see what it returns.